# mongoid unit test without running mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb, unit-testing, testing, mongoid

I recently started working with Mongoid using MongoLab. I don't actually have a local MongoDB instance running (and don't really need it). However, I want to unit test some of the document creation.

Is there an equivalent of SQLite for Mongo? Or some in-memory way to write tests for the business logic around the Mongoid document creation?

What I'd love to be able to do would be to call the main method of the class that creates the Mongoid documents, then introspect on the document structure/data without it persisting. But Mongoid doesn't seem to allow this, unless I'm missing something.

What is the best approach to test the structure/validations/relationships/etc. of Mongoid documents *without* running MongoDB or persisting them?

Comment: What "main method" are you talking about here?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. By "main method" I just meant the main public interface/method for the class that creates the document. I have a Manager class that creates Mongoid documents and I want to unit test the manager class, verifying that the Mongoid documents are correct... but without having to actually persist them to any MongoDB.

Comment: What is the method called?

Comment: Ryan, it has nothing to do with the method name. I'm just asking if there are ways to create Mongoid documents _solely_ in memory for testing. That way, I can create them in unit tests and not require any DB access. That's what I'm after here.

Comment: If you're calling `create`, it will persist automatically. If you're calling `new`, it will create an in-memory object. So yes, it _does_ matter what method you're calling.

Comment: Oh! I'm so sorry! thought you meant what method in my Repository class I'm calling, not what method on the Mongoid objects. Wow... I totally misunderstood.  Anyway, I'm tracking with you now. I thought I was calling new (or build) everywhere in the tests, but I'll double-check. I also thought that if I have a reference relationship it seems to save that regardless of whether I do create or new.  Maybe I missed something, though.  Again, apologies for misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was doing "find_or_initialize_by". I should have realized that. This, in effect, required that an actual database existed to do the find against.

What I ended up doing for my tests, so they could run fast and not have an external DB dependency, is to wrap the "find_or_initialize_by" in methods, and then I can mock those methods and control the returns.

So for a new object, I can mock that and return a new Mongoid document
For an existing object, I can build a new Mongoid document populated with data and then mock the method and return that.

This allows me to simulate, in my tests, scenarios where I am creating new documents and scenarios where I am finding and updating existing documents.

I also had to stub the save method, which means I have to handle validations separately.

It seems like a lot of work, but the value here is that I can run my tests really fast, and I don't have a DB dependency... which I had before. This is particularly nice since I don't even have a local DB... I'm just using Mongolab.com, and I definitely don't want my unit tests making remote DB calls.

I hope this helps someone else. It was quite an ordeal to figure this all out and get it working, but now I have nice, fast, dependency-free unit tests!